# Magento filter order collection by product sku

Tags: magento

I'm using magento 1.7 and I need to get all orders from certain increment_id containing at least one item matching a sku.

Here's what I have:

```
      $orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('status',
            array(
                'nin' => array(
                    'new',
                    'pending',
                    'pending_payment',
                    'holded',
                    'canceled')
            ))
        ->addFieldToFilter('increment_id', array('gteq' => $last_order));
```

If I add a line with:

```
   $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('sku', $findSku);
```

I will get a PHP fatal error since 'sku' is not a field. I've tried addAttributeToFilter() and it won't work either.

I know I need to build a join with another table, but I don't know how joins are made in Magento and I don't know which table I should join to.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

SKUs are placed in order item table not in orders.
Your final query must look like this one:

```
SELECT o.increment_id 
FROM sales_flat_order_item oi 
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order o ON o.entity_id = oi.order_id 
WHERE product_id=XXX 
ORDER BY o.increment_id DESC;
```

This query can be done using nearly such syntax:

```
$orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection();
$orderItem
     ->getSelect()
     ->joinInner(array('order' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')), 'order.entity_id = main_table.order_id' )
     ->where('product_id=?', $productId)
     ->order('main_table.order_id DESC');
```

Comment: You may join order item table to orders table and use group_concat mysql function to concat all skus related to 1 order.

Comment: The correct entity is 'sales/order_item' not 'sales_order/item'

Comment: You also have a third `:` up there (I can't edit it)

Comment: @freento, this is working fine but i want to get order by specific year so how can i do that ?

Comment: How to get order ids between two dates in this ?